# Create m3u8 and stream from server

Tags: asp.net, ffmpeg, http-live-streaming, m3u8

How can I create m3u8 file with using ffmpeg on a server (**Convert Server**) and send it to another server (**Storage Server**) and stream from there(Live Stream)?

I want to handle it with asp.net.

How can I do it?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

HTTP Live Streaming (HLS) can be easily produced by ffmpeg ([official documentation on HLS muxer](https://www.ffmpeg.org/ffmpeg-formats.html#hls-1)):

> ffmpeg -i input.mp4 out.m3u8

It is possible to specify another live streaming server as output (instead of m3u8 file), see https://trac.ffmpeg.org/wiki/StreamingGuide for more details on this.

From ASP.NET you can execute ffmpeg with System.Diagnostics.Process.

Comment: Can I handle this process in my own servers?(without using wowza,....)
If I can, How to do that(is there any remommendation)?